# class is not working in css

Tags: css, html

i cant able to set width of my text field [newbie to css]
this is my code

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain" >
<input type="text" name="postquestion" class="ps" value="" placeholder="What's Your Question..?"data-mini="true"/>
</div>
```

this is worked

```
.ui-input-text{
    width:150px !important;
}
```

but this is not worked

```
.ps
{
width:150px !important;
}
```

i dont know why, i googled alot but i didnt get my answer. please help me.

Comment: as you can see on this fiddle, the above works fine : http://jsfiddle.net/TNWbh/

Comment: You are probably using some javascript which interferes with your code and removes classes. Have a look at your mark up in the Google Chrome inspector or firebug.

Comment: try div .ps { width: 150px !important }

Comment: i see the jquery-mobile tag on your question. What is most likely happening is that jquery is adding more classes to you input tag that has a width style.

Comment: @hexblot yes,i checked it in jsfiddle.but still not working to me. look at this image.
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7s0BYiHsMBtdEgzVUNlM3hhLWc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: try div input.ps { width: 150px !important; }

Comment: since the above works in jsfiddle but not for you, there is something else on the page that affects it. Can't really help you there unless we see more of the page.

Answer (score 0):

`.ui-input-text` is what defined in the framework. If you messup with it, then it'll update the width.

But it'll affect the width of your textboxes throughout the application. Also remember jQuery MObile will remove custom styles and force it's styles upon initialisation.

You can do a inline styling as below to change the textbox size without hacking the framework.

```
<input type="text" id="postquestion" name="postquestion" class="ps" value="" placeholder="What's Your Question..?"data-mini="true" style="width:50px"/>
```

here is a workign fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/UyFWM/

Comment: but it comes like this to me..
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7s0BYiHsMBtRlZtekEwRTZrMTQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: did you check the fiddle?? if you wrap it inside `fieldcontain` div then the textbox will come like dat. Read the jQuery mobile documentation